# Searching on class tags with multiple spaces and wildcards with BeautifulSoup

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, findall

I am trying to use BeautifulSoup to find all `div` containers with the class attribute beginning by "foo bar".  I had hoped the following would work:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

import re

soup.findAll('div',class_=re.compile('^foo bar'))
```

However, it seems that the class definition is separated into a list, like `['foo','bar']`, such that regular expressions are not able to accomplish my task.  Is there a way I can accomplish this task? (I have reviewed a number of other posts, but have not found a working solution)

Comment: I'm having the same problem. Did you solve it?

Answer (score 0):

You can use a syntax with a [function that needs to return `True` or `False`](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#searching-by-css-class), a lambda can do the trick too:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as soup
html = '''
<div class="foo bar bing"></div>
<div class="foo bang"></div>
<div class="foo bar1 bang"></div>
'''
soup = soup(html, 'lxml')
res = soup.find_all('div', class_=lambda s:s.startswith('foo bar '))
print(res)
>>> [<div class="foo bar bing"></div>]
```

---

```
res = soup.find_all('div', class_=lambda s:s.startswith('foo bar')) # without space
print(res)
>>> [<div class="foo bar bing"></div>, <div class="foo bar1 bang"></div>]
```

---

Another possible syntax with a function :

```
def is_a_match(clas):
    return clas.startswith('foo bar')

res = soup.find_all('div', class_=is_a_match)
```

Maybe this answer can help you too : https://stackoverflow.com/a/46719313/6655211