# BeautifulSoup and class with spaces

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

With BeautifulSoul and Python, I want to `find_all` all the `tr` items matching a given class attribute that contains multiple names like this one:

```
<tr class="admin-bookings-table-row bookings-history-row  paid   ">
```

I have tried several ways to match that class. Regular expressions, wildcards but I always get an empty list.

Is there any way to use regular expressions, wildcards or how to match this class?

There is posted the same question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36996722/searching-on-class-tags-with-multiple-spaces-and-wildcards-with-beautifulsoup) with no answer.

Comment: For the record, a class can't have spaces in it. This element has multiple classes.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

you can use a [css selector](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#searching-by-css-class) to match many classes :

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as soup
html = '''
<tr class="admin-bookings-table-row bookings-history-row  paid   "></tr>
<tr class="admin-bookings-table-row  nope  paid   "></tr>
'''
soup = soup(html, 'lxml')

res = soup.select('tr.admin-bookings-table-row.bookings-history-row.paid')
print(res)

>>> [<tr class="admin-bookings-table-row bookings-history-row paid "></tr>]
```

---

Otherwise, maybe this answer can help you too :
https://stackoverflow.com/a/46719501/6655211

Comment: interesting approach.  can css selector just return the first match like `soup.find()`?

Comment: Ofc, you can try with `select_one`

Answer (score 7):

HTML class can't contain spaces. This element has multiple classes.

Searching by either of these classes works:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

html = '<tr id="history_row_938220" style="" class="admin-bookings-table-row bookings-history-row  paid   ">'


soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')

print(soup.find_all(attrs={'class': 'admin-bookings-table-row'}))
print(soup.find_all(attrs={'class': 'bookings-history-row'}))
print(soup.find_all(attrs={'class': 'paid'}))
```

All output

```
[<tr class="admin-bookings-table-row bookings-history-row paid " 
 id="history_row_938220" style=""></tr>]
```

Comment: The question seems to be to find all `tr` items that have multiple classes.  I'm not exactly sure if this finds that.

Comment: @BradSolomon I've just shown that using *either* of the 3 classes finds the element so I'm not sure what OP is doing in order to get an empty list.

Comment: That's not the question.  "I want to find_all all tr items with a given class that contain multiple spaces."  If you had a tag `class="paid"`, your `attrs` filter would return it even though it has just 1 class.

Comment: @BradSolomon Now we are getting into semantics. `"I want to find_all all tr items with a given class that contain multiple spaces."` is wrong (and impossible) by definition, since there is no such thing as `"a given class that contain multiple spaces"`. Beautiful Soup uses an inclusion logic when searching by class (the same behavior as above can be achived by passing a list of classes: `soup.find_all(attrs={'class': ['admin-bookings-table-row', 'bookings-history-row', 'paid']})`)

Comment: Ha. I know that, but the intent seems clearly to equate multiple spaces with multiple classes.  Let's try to get clarification.

Answer (score 1):

> I want to `find_all` all `tr` items with a given class that contain
>   multiple spaces.

Multiple spaces actually indicates multiple classes within the tag.  You can filter on `tr` tags that have multiple classes like so:

```
html_doc = """
<html><head><title>a title here</title></head>
<body>
<tr class="admin-bookings-table-row bookings-history-row  paid   " id="link1">Elsie</tr>,
<tr class="oneclass" id="link2">Lacie</tr>
<tr class="tag1 tag2" id="link3">Tillie</tr>
"""
soup = BeautifulSoup(html_doc, 'html.parser')
filt = [tag for tag in soup.find_all('tr') if len(tag.get('class')) > 1]

filt  # Only 2 of 3 tags returned--excludes tag with just 1 class
# [<tr class="admin-bookings-table-row bookings-history-row paid " id="link1">Elsie</tr>,
#  <tr class="tag1 tag2" id="link3">Tillie</tr>]
```

Or, using a lambda:

```
soup.find_all(lambda tag: tag.name=='tr' and len(tag.get('class')) > 1)
```

Comment: "with a given class"  not sure OP is looking for all multiple classes

Comment: Ok, I see what you mean.  @RuBiCK, am i misinterpreting?

Comment: I would like to be able to use regex and handle a string :) The goal in this case is find by "admin-bookings-table-row bookings-history-row paid" , only three classes at the same time

Comment: @RuBiCK in that case I'm even more confused about what you're trying to do here then, unfortunately.  If you want to find "all classes at the same time," then you can just use `find_all` without any specification of attributes.