# BeautifulSoup Finding Class with Spaces?

Tags: html, python-3.x, xml, beautifulsoup

With BeautifulSoup and python3.9 using lmxl as the parser,

I would like to find the `<div, class="playlistAPI..."` from the image below.

[image]

but when I do `x = soup.find("div", class_="playlistInterface")` and print, I get:

```
<div class="playlistInterface" style="position: relative; width: 100%; height: 100%">
<div class="mwPlayerContainer player-out">
<div class="videoHolder"><div class="videoDisplay">
<video class="persistentNativePlayer" id="kaltura_player_" kentryid="1_o54seuc8" kpartnerid="1493231" kuiconfid="41642851" kwidgetid="1_3t8nz2gs" poster="data:image/png,%89PNG%0D%0A%1A%0A%00%00%00%0DIHDR%00%00%00%01%00%00%00%01%08%02%00%00%00%90wS%DE%00%00%00%01sRGB%00%AE%CE%1C%E9%00%00%00%09pHYs%00%00%0B%13%00%00%0B%13%01%00%9A%9C%18%00%00%00%07tIME%07%DB%0B%0A%17%041%80%9B%E7%F2%00%00%00%19tEXtComment%00Created%20with%20GIMPW%81%0E%17%00%00%00%0CIDAT%08%D7c%60%60%60%00%00%00%04%00%01'4'%0A%00%00%00%00IEND%AEB%60%82" preload="none">
</video>
</div></div> </div>
</div>
```

IE, it doesn't appear and I can't find it using `x.find("div", class_="playlistAPI medialistContainer unselectable k-vertical")`

I tried what was suggested in the following [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46718366/beautifulsoup-and-class-with-spaces) and the trail of threads that were linked from there, but I have had no luck.

Is there a way to do this?  Or am I missing something obvious?

[Here is the URL](https://cdnapisec.kaltura.com/html5/html5lib/v2.90/mwEmbedFrame.php/p/1493231/uiconf_id/41642851?wid=1_3t8nz2gs&iframeembed=true&playerId=kaltura_player_&flashvars%5BplaylistAPI.kpl0Id%5D=1_ylmxnjry&flashvars%5Bks%5D=&&flashvars%5BimageDefaultDuration%5D=30&flashvars%5BakamaiHD.loadingPolicy%5D=preInitialize&flashvars%5BakamaiHD.asyncInit%5D=true&flashvars%5BtwoPhaseManifest%5D=true&flashvars%5BstreamerType%5D=hdnetworkmanifest&flashvars%5BlocalizationCode%5D=en&flashvars%5BleadWithHTML5%5D=true&flashvars%5BnextPrevBtn.plugin%5D=true&flashvars%5BsideBarContainer.plugin%5D=true&flashvars%5BsideBarContainer.position%5D=left&flashvars%5BsideBarContainer.clickToClose%5D=true&flashvars%5Bchapters.plugin%5D=true&flashvars%5Bchapters.layout%5D=vertical&flashvars%5Bchapters.thumbnailRotator%5D=false&flashvars%5BstreamSelector.plugin%5D=true&flashvars%5BEmbedPlayer.SpinnerTarget%5D=videoHolder&flashvars%5BdualScreen.plugin%5D=true&flashvars%5BplaylistAPI.playlistUrl%5D=https://nyitmedicine.mediaspace.kaltura.com/playlist/details/%7BplaylistAPI.kpl0Id%7D/categoryid/217366723)

Thank you in advance.

Comment: if possible can you provide URL

Comment: simply because you need to include Period `.` within the classes names ! you are matching 4 different classes, use `playlistAPI.medialistContainer.unselectable.k-vertical`

Comment: Using periods also returns None.  I have provided the URL.  Feel free to take a crack at it.

Comment: @ACB_prgm do you want to find  title of Lectures in that div container??

Comment: @BhavyaParikh yes!  I am trying to get the title and duration of each lecture.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As already explained in your linked question: Spaces in a CSS class name separate the tag into multiple CSS classes. You can do a list comparison to find the tag that belongs to all the classes:

```py
x.find("div", class_=["playlistAPI", "medialistContainer", "undetectable", "k-vertical"])
```

Comment: I tried this, it returns None.  Also, the results for the entire level do not include that div.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this by using selenium's webdriver and sleeping in between my GET request and creating the soup.

```
import time
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs
from selenium import webdriver
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager

driver = webdriver.Chrome(ChromeDriverManager().install(), options=options_)
driver.get(Kaltura_URL)
    time.sleep(2)
    content = driver.page_source.encode("utf-8").strip()
    soup = bs(content, "lxml")

    for item in soup.find_all("li"):
        print(item.text)
```

I don't really understand why this works, other than I think it "tricks" the URL into thinking there is an actual user accessing the URL rather than a bot.

If you understand why, please comment and let me know!  I want to learn why, not just get things to work.