# BeautifulSoup find class with space

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, python-requests

I am trying to get price info using BS4 with Python.

This is the `<p>` class from which I am trying to extract the value of `'$3245'`.

```
<div class="s1fqyqkq-3 bDmzjk">
  <div class="s1fqyqkq-4 ckAXTq">Price Info</div>
    <p class="s1fqyqkq-5 dekHBg">$3245</p>
</div>
```

And this is the code I am trying to use to get the data, but it's returning "**None**"

```
headers = {
        "Connection": "keep-alive",
        "User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/72.0.3626.121 Safari/537.36"
    }
    req = requests.get(url, headers=headers)
    soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(req.text, 'html.parser')
    
    result = soup.find("div", {"class": "s1fqyqkq-5 dekHBg"})
    print(result)
```

I tried all suggestions, but I am still I receiving "None" as a result.

I tried the suggestion [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46718366/beautifulsoup-and-class-with-spaces) to no avail. Any idea what I am missing?

Comment: It looks like it's the `<p>` tag not the `<div>` that has class `"s1fqyqkq-5 dekHBg"`

Comment: Yes but still, it's returning None..

Comment: 1st make sure page is not created dynamically by javascript then try `soup.select("body > div > p")`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*While cooking your `soup` taste it to ensure it comes with all expected ingridients.*

Main issue, content is created dynamically by `javascript` so you wont find your information that way, cause `requests` do not act like a browser and is not able to render all information.

To get informations take a look at the script variables and extract the JSON strings.

```
import json, requests

url = 'https://www.cimri.com/cep-telefonlari/en-ucuz-apple-iphone-11-64gb-4gb-ram-6-1-inc-12mp-akilli-cep-telefonu-siyah-fiyatlari,337340793'

jsonData = json.loads(re.search(r"window.productDetails = (.*?);", requests.get(url).text).group(1))
jsonData
```

###### Output

```
{'id': '337340793', 'path': '/cep-telefonlari/en-ucuz-apple-iphone-11-64gb-4gb-ram-6-1-inc-12mp-akilli-cep-telefonu-siyah-fiyatlari,337340793', 'itemType': 0, 'mainId': 337341638, 'title': 'Apple iPhone 11 64GB 4GB Ram 6.1 inç 12MP Akıllı Cep Telefonu Siyah', 'offers': [{'id': '506482765', 'price': 13135.85, 'title': 'Yeni Apple iPhone 11 (64\xa0GB) - Siyah', 'shipping': {'fee': 0, 'day': 0}, 'merchant': {'id': '10370', 'url': 'https://www.amazon.com.tr', 'seller': 'Amazon.com.tr', 'slogan': 'Amazon.com.tr uygulamasında ilk 150 TL ve üzeri alışverişe 40 TL indirim ', 'onlyApp': False}, 'unitPrice': None, 'numbers': [], 'sponsored': False, 'feedLastProcess': 1655495611798}, {'id': '894741295', 'price': 13149, 'title': 'iPhone 11 64 GB Aksesuarsız Kutu Siyah', 'shipping': {'fee': 0, 'day': 3}, 'merchant': {'id': '10109', 'url': 'https://www.trendyol.com/', 'seller': 'Trendyol', 'slogan': "Tüm İhtiyaçların Trendyol'da, Tek Tıkla Kapında!", 'onlyApp': False}, 'unitPrice': None, 'numbers': [], 'sponsored': True, 'feedLastProcess': 1655493405188}, {'id': '887498622', 'price': 13249, 'title': 'Apple iPhone 11 64 GB Cep Telefonu Siyah', 'shipping': {'fee': 0, 'day': 2}, 'merchant': {'id': '10416', 'url': 'https://www.a101.com.tr/', 'seller': None, 'slogan': 'A101|Harca Harca Bitmez', 'onlyApp': False}, 'unitPrice': None, 'numbers': [], 'sponsored': False, 'feedLastProcess': 1655489830306}, {'id': '767094934', 'price': 13299, 'title': 'iPhone 11 64 GB Siyah', 'shipping': {'fee': 0, 'day': None}, 'merchant': {'id': '4093', 'url': 'http://www.turkcell.com.tr', 'seller': None, 'slogan': None, 'onlyApp': False}, 'unitPrice': None, 'numbers': [], 'sponsored': False, 'feedLastProcess': 1655494357178}, {'id': '855428213', 'price': 13350, 'title': 'iPhone 11 64 GB Siyah (Apple Türkiye Garantili) - (Aksesuarsız Kutu)', 'shipping': {'fee': 0, 'day': 0}, 'merchant': {'id': '12192', 'url': 'https://www.needion.com/', 'seller': None, 'slogan': 'Alan Memnun, Satan Memnun', 'onlyApp': False}, 'unitPrice': None, 'numbers': [], 'sponsored': True, 'feedLastProcess': 1655495321932}, {'id': '914643935', 'price': 13379, 'title': 'Apple iPhone 11 64GB Akıllı Cep Telefonu Siyah ( Apple Türkiye Garantili )', 'shipping': {'fee': 0, 'day': 1}, 'merchant': {'id': '12665', 'url': 'https://wnt.com.tr/', 'seller': None, 'slogan': None, 'onlyApp': False}, 'unitPrice': None, 'numbers': [], 'sponsored': False, 'feedLastProcess': 1655494393339}, {'id': '491596021', 'price': 13398.99, 'title': 'iPhone 11 64 GB - Siyah - Aksesuarsız Kutu', 'shipping': {'fee': None, 'day': 0}, 'merchant': {'id': '1497', 'url': 'http://www.hepsiburada.com', 'seller': 'Hepsiburada', 'slogan': 'Türkiye’de İlk Defa Alışveriş Kredisi Burada', 'onlyApp': False}, 'unitPrice': None, 'numbers': [], 'sponsored': False, 'feedLastProcess': 1655495861494}, {'id': '1027767764', 'price': 13459, 'title': 'Apple iPhone 11 64GB Siyah Cep Telefonu (Apple Türkiye Garantili) (Siyah)', 'shipping': {'fee': 0, 'day': 1}, 'merchant': {'id': '5825', 'url': 'https://www.vodafone.com.tr/', 'seller': 'GENÇPA', 'slogan': 'Vodafone Her Şey Yanımda Alışverişlerinizde Kargo Bedava, Vodafone’lulara İlk Siparişe 15GB Hediye!', 'onlyApp': True}, 'unitPrice': None, 'numbers': [], 'sponsored': False, 'feedLastProcess': 1655495537182}, {'id': '952479181', 'price': 13499, 'title': 'iPhone 11 64 GB Aksesuarsız Kutu Siyah', 'shipping': {'fee': 0, 'day': 0}, 'merchant': {'id': '10109', 'url': 'https://www.trendyol.com/', 'seller': 'Teknosa', 'slogan': "Tüm İhtiyaçların Trendyol'da, Tek Tıkla Kapında!", 'onlyApp': False}, 'unitPrice': None, 'numbers': [], 'sponsored': False, 'feedLastProcess': 1655493405188}, {'id': '1032790438', 'price': 13499, 'title': 'Apple iPhone 11 64 GB Siyah (Apple Türkiye Garantili) (Siyah)', 'shipping': {'fee': 0, 'day': 1}, 'merchant': {'id': '5825', 'url': 'https://www.vodafone.com.tr/', 'seller': 'CepHane Teknoloji', 'slogan': 'Vodafone Her Şey Yanımda Alışverişlerinizde Kargo Bedava, Vodafone’lulara İlk Siparişe 15GB Hediye!', 'onlyApp': True}, 'unitPrice': None, 'numbers': [], 'sponsored': False, 'feedLastProcess': 1655495537182}, {'id': '1063638766', 'price': 13509, 'title': 'Apple iPhone 11 64 GB (Apple Türkiye Garantili) siyah', 'shipping': {'fee': 0, 'day': 2}, 'merchant': {'id': '7000', 'url': 'http://www.n11.com', 'seller': 'cokteknolojik', 'slogan': 'Hayat Sana Gelir', 'onlyApp': False}, 'unitPrice': None, 'numbers': [], 'sponsored': False, 'feedLastProcess': 1655495952093}, {'id': '930481030', 'price': 13559, 'title': 'iPhone 11 64GB Black', 'shipping': {'fee': 0, 'day': 1}, 'merchant': {'id': '13105', 'url': 'https://www.inbox.com.tr/', 'seller': None, 'slogan': None, 'onlyApp': False}, 'unitPrice': None, 'numbers': [], 'sponsored': False, 'feedLastProcess': 1655491323973}, {'id': '1007434732', 'price': 13633, 'title': 'Apple iPhone 11 64 GB (Apple Türkiye Garantili) siyah', 'shipping': {'fee': 0, 'day': 1}, 'merchant': {'id': '7000', 'url': 'http://www.n11.com', 'seller': 'yukseliletisim', 'slogan': 'Hayat Sana Gelir', 'onlyApp': False}, 'unitPrice': None, 'numbers': [], 'sponsored': False, 'feedLastProcess': 1655495952093}, {'id': '912636803', 'price': 13699, 'title': 'Apple iPhone 11 64GB Siyah - MHDA3TU/A', 'shipping': {'fee': 0, 'day': 1}, 'merchant': {'id': '11403', 'url': 'https://gurgencler.com.tr/', 'seller': None, 'slogan': '10.000TL üzeri alışverişinize 500TL Bankkart Lira hediye!', 'onlyApp': False}, 'unitPrice': None, 'numbers': [], 'sponsored': False, 'feedLastProcess': 1655492821318}, {'id': '974603297', 'price': 13779, 'title': 'IPhone 11 64 GB Siyah', 'shipping': {'fee': 0, 'day': 0}, 'merchant': {'id': '12938', 'url': 'https://www.cepux.com.tr/', 'seller': None, 'slogan': 'Cepux Kazandırır!', 'onlyApp': False}, 'unitPrice': None, 'numbers': [], 'sponsored': False, 'feedLastProcess': 1655495878822}, {'id': '960442769', 'price': 13779, 'title': 'Apple iPhone 11 64 GB Aksesuarsız Kutu Siyah (Siyah)', 'shipping': {'fee': 0, 'day': 1}, 'merchant': {'id': '5825', 'url': 'https://www.vodafone.com.tr/', 'seller': 'Tokdemir Bilişim Teknolojileri', 'slogan': 'Vodafone Her Şey Yanımda Alışverişlerinizde Kargo Bedava, Vodafone’lulara İlk Siparişe 15GB Hediye!', 'onlyApp': True}, 'unitPrice': None, 'numbers': [], 'sponsored': False, 'feedLastProcess': 1655495537182}, {'id': '965671448', 'price': 13789, 'title': 'iPhone 11 64 GB Siyah', 'shipping': {'fee': 0, 'day': None}, 'merchant': {'id': '4093', 'url': 'http://www.turkcell.com.tr', 'seller': None, 'slogan': None, 'onlyApp': False}, 'unitPrice': None, 'numbers': [], 'sponsored': False, 'feedLastProcess': 1655494357178}, {'id': '808307738', 'price': 13798, 'title': 'iPhone 11 64 GB Siyah', 'shipping': {'fee': 0, 'day': None}, 'merchant': {'id': '4093', 'url': 'http://www.turkcell.com.tr', 'seller': None, 'slogan': None, 'onlyApp': False}, 'unitPrice': None, 'numbers': [], 'sponsored': False, 'feedLastProcess': 1655494357178}, {'id': '1059226040', 'price': 13799, 'title': 'Apple iPhone 11 64 GB (Apple Türkiye Garantili) siyah', 'shipping': {'fee': 0, 'day': 1}, 'merchant': {'id': '7000', 'url': 'http://www.n11.com', 'seller': 'integrabilisim', 'slogan': 'Hayat Sana Gelir', 'onlyApp': False}, 'unitPrice': None, 'numbers': [], 'sponsored': False, 'feedLastProcess': 1655495952093}, {'id': '734101431', 'price': 13799, 'title': 'Iphone 11 64 Gb Siyah Aksesuarsız Kutu', 'shipping': {'fee': 0, 'day': 1}, 'merchant': {'id': '11512', 'url': 'https://www.pttavm.com', 'seller': 'BittiBitiyor', 'slogan': None, 'onlyApp': False}, 'unitPrice': None, 'numbers': [], 'sponsored': False, 'feedLastProcess': 1655495542557}, {'id': '765227763', 'price': 14484, 'title': 'Apple iPhone 11 64Gb Akıllı Telefon Siyah', 'shipping': {'fee': 0, 'day': 0}, 'merchant': {'id': '46', 'url': 'http://www.teknosa.com/', 'seller': 'Bittibitiyor', 'slogan': "Sepette 2.500 TL'ye Varan İndirimler", 'onlyApp': False}, 'unitPrice': None, 'numbers': [], 'sponsored': False, 'feedLastProcess': 1655489853593}, {'id': '765957525', 'price': 14499, 'title': 'iPhone 11 64 Gb Siyah', 'shipping': {'fee': 15, 'day': 1}, 'merchant': {'id': '11375', 'url': 'https://www.vatanbilgisayar.com/', 'seller': None, 'slogan': None, 'onlyApp': False}, 'unitPrice': None, 'numbers': [], 'sponsored': False, 'feedLastProcess': 1655489535355}, {'id': '765434969', 'price': 14499, 'title': 'APPLE iPhone 11 64GB Akıllı Telefon Siyah', 'shipping': {'fee': 0, 'day': None}, 'merchant': {'id': '4230', 'url': 'http://www.mediamarkt.com.tr/', 'seller': None, 'slogan': '250 TL ve üzeri alışverişlerde geçerli ücretsiz kargo', 'onlyApp': False}, 'unitPrice': None, 'numbers': [], 'sponsored': False, 'feedLastProcess': 1655489226707}, {'id': '765500161', 'price': 14549.03, 'title': 'Apple İphone 11 64Gb Siyah - Mhda3tu/A 194252097335', 'shipping': {'fee': 0, 'day': 1}, 'merchant': {'id': '10052', 'url': 'http://www.troyestore.com/', 'seller': None, 'slogan': 'Apple Yetkili Satıcı, Apple Yetkili Teknik Servis', 'onlyApp': False}, 'unitPrice': None, 'numbers': [], 'sponsored': False, 'feedLastProcess': 1655493437121}, {'id': '765498940', 'price': 14999, 'title': 'Apple iPhone 11 64 Gb Siyah Cep Telefonu', 'shipping': {'fee': 0, 'day': None}, 'merchant': {'id': '10313', 'url': 'https://www.migros.com.tr/', 'seller': None, 'slogan': '250 TL ve Üzeri Ücretsiz Teslimat', 'onlyApp': False}, 'unitPrice': None, 'numbers': [], 'sponsored': False, 'feedLastProcess': 1655488948137}, {'id': '765987003', 'price': 14999, 'title': 'Apple iPhone 11 64GB Siyah Yeni Cep Telefonu', 'shipping': {'fee': 0, 'day': 2}, 'merchant': {'id': '10604', 'url': 'https://www.beko.com.tr/', 'seller': None, 'slogan': 'Ücretsiz ve Hızlı Teslimat ile Beko Kapında!', 'onlyApp': False}, 'unitPrice': None, 'numbers': [], 'sponsored': False, 'feedLastProcess': 1655492802285}, {'id': '765350098', 'price': 14999, 'title': 'Apple iPhone 11 64GB Siyah Yeni Cep Telefonu', 'shipping': {'fee': 0, 'day': 2}, 'merchant': {'id': '10591', 'url': 'https://www.arcelik.com.tr/', 'seller': None, 'slogan': 'Ücretsiz ve Hızlı Teslimat ile Arçelik Kapında!', 'onlyApp': False}, 'unitPrice': None, 'numbers': [], 'sponsored': False, 'feedLastProcess': 1655492539972}, {'id': '765171664', 'price': 14999, 'title': 'Apple iPhone 11 64GB Siyah (New Edt)', 'shipping': {'fee': 0, 'day': None}, 'merchant': {'id': '9334', 'url': 'http://www.evkur.com.tr/', 'seller': None, 'slogan': 'Hiç Peşinatsız Kredi Kartsız 24 Aya Varan Taksitlerle', 'onlyApp': False}, 'unitPrice': None, 'numbers': [], 'sponsored': False, 'feedLastProcess': 1655491644137}, {'id': '806067367', 'price': 15292.64, 'title': 'İphone 11 64 Gb', 'shipping': {'fee': 0, 'day': 0}, 'merchant': {'id': '5164', 'url': 'http://www.gittigidiyor.com/', 'seller': 'gncpazar', 'slogan': "Yapı Kredi World'e Özel 50 TL'ye Varan Worldpuan", 'onlyApp': False}, 'unitPrice': None, 'numbers': [], 'sponsored': False, 'feedLastProcess': 1655495287185}, {'id': '1068272963', 'price': 15599, 'title': 'İphone 11 64 Gb Siyah(kvk Garantili)', 'shipping': {'fee': 0, 'day': 3}, 'merchant': {'id': '5164', 'url': 'http://www.gittigidiyor.com/', 'seller': 'AYAZGRUP', 'slogan': "Yapı Kredi World'e Özel 50 TL'ye Varan Worldpuan", 'onlyApp': False}, 'unitPrice': None, 'numbers': [], 'sponsored': False, 'feedLastProcess': 1655495287185}, {'id': '793747418', 'price': 17591.37, 'title': 'Apple IPHONE 11 64GB Apple IPHONE 11 64GB Cep Telefonu (Apple Türkiye Garantili)', 'shipping': {'fee': 25, 'day': None}, 'merchant': {'id': '11898', 'url': 'https://www.turkuaztrade.com/', 'seller': None, 'slogan': 'Simply The Best / Kısaca En İyisi', 'onlyApp': False}, 'unitPrice': None, 'numbers': [], 'sponsored': False, 'feedLastProcess': 1655494006222}], 'imageIds': [219571586, 219571585, 219571582, 219571577, 219575009], 'review': {'count': 95, 'rate': 4}, 'badge': {'discountRatio': 0, 'isNew': False}, 'metaData': {'title': 'Apple iPhone 11 64GB 4GB Ram 6.1 inç 12MP Akıllı Cep Telefonu Siyah Fiyatları ve Özellikleri', 'description': "Apple iPhone 11 64GB 4GB Ram 6.1 inç 12MP Akıllı Cep Telefonu Siyah modellerini tüm detayları ile Cimri.com'da inceleyin! Siz de Cimri.com ile Apple iPhone 11 64GB 4GB Ram 6.1 inç 12MP Akıllı Cep Telefonu Siyah fiyatlarına ve özelliklerine kolayca ulaşabilir, ürüne ait kullanıcı yorum ve değerlendirmelerini inceleyebilirsiniz. Dilerseniz fiyat ve özellik karşılaştıraması yapabilir ve son 1 yıla ait fiyat değişimlerini takip edebilirsiniz. Cimri.com ile siz de en ucuz Apple iPhone 11 64GB 4GB Ram 6.1 inç 12MP Akıllı Cep Telefonu Siyah fırsatlarını kaçırmayın!"}, 'specs': [{'name': 'Model Bilgisi', 'specEntries': [{'name': 'Iphone Modelleri', 'value': 'iPhone 11', 'order': 1}], 'order': 1}, {'name': 'Ekran Özellikleri', 'specEntries': [{'name': 'Ekran Boyutu', 'value': '6.1 inç', 'order': 3}, {'name': 'Ekran Teknolojisi', 'value': 'IPS LCD', 'order': 5}, {'name': 'Yan Ekran', 'value': 'Yok', 'order': 14}, {'name': 'Mavi Işık Filtresi', 'value': 'Var', 'order': 15}, {'name': 'Çözünürlük Standartı', 'value': 'HD+', 'order': 16}, {'name': 'Karanlık Modu', 'value': 'Var', 'order': 16}, {'name': 'Ekran Çözünürlüğü', 'value': '828x1792 Piksel', 'order': 21}, {'name': 'Ekran Gövde Oranı', 'value': '79 %', 'order': 21}, {'name': 'Piksel Yoğunluğu', 'value': '326 PPI', 'order': 22}, {'name': 'Multi Touch', 'value': 'Var', 'order': 22}, {'name': 'Dokunmatik Türü', 'value': 'Kapasitif Ekran', 'order': 23}, {'name': 'Ekran Parlaklığı (cd-m²)', 'value': '625', 'order': 26}, {'name': 'Çizilmeye Karşı Dayanıklılık', 'value': 'Var', 'order': 28}, {'name': 'Ekran Kontrast Oranı', 'value': '1400:1', 'order': 29}, {'name': 'Sürekli Açık Ekran', 'value': 'Yok', 'order': 30}], 'order': 1}, {'name': 'Teknik Özellikler', 'specEntries': [{'name': 'İşlemci Modeli', 'value': 'Apple A13 Bionic', 'order': 1}, {'name': 'İşlemci Frekansı', 'value': '2.66 GHz', 'order': 2}, {'name': 'RAM Kapasitesi', 'value': '4 GB RAM', 'order': 6}, {'name': 'İşletim Sistemi Versiyonu', 'value': 'iOS 13', 'order': 8}, {'name': 'İşletim Sistemi', 'value': 'iOS', 'order': 19}, {'name': 'İşlemci Çekirdek Sayısı', 'value': '6 Çekirdek', 'order': 26}, {'name': 'CPU Üretim Süreci', 'value': '7 nm', 'order': 27}, {'name': 'İşlemci Mimarisi', 'value': '64 bit', 'order': 28}, {'name': 'Ram Tipi', 'value': 'LPDDR4x', 'order': 30}, {'name': 'Ram Kanal Sayısı', 'value': 'Çift Kanal', 'order': 31}], 'order': 2}, {'name': 'Kamera Özellikleri', 'specEntries': [{'name': 'Kamera Çözünürlüğü', 'value': '12 MP', 'order': 4}, {'name': 'Ön (Selfie) Kamera Diyafram Açıklığı', 'value': 'F2.2', 'order': 6}, {'name': 'Ön (Selfie) Kamera Çözünürlüğü', 'value': '12 MP', 'order': 8}, {'name': 'Diyafram Açıklığı', 'value': 'F1.8', 'order': 9}, {'name': 'İkinci Arka Kamera', 'value': 'Var', 'order': 10}, {'name': 'İkinci Arka Kamera Diyafram Açıklığı', 'value': 'F2.4', 'order': 10}, {'name': 'Video Kayıt Çözünürlüğü', 'value': '2160p', 'order': 11}, {'name': 'Video FPS Değeri', 'value': '60 FPS', 'order': 12}, {'name': 'İkinci Arka Kamera Çözünürlüğü', 'value': '12 MP', 'order': 22}, {'name': 'Görüntü Sabitleyici', 'value': 'Var', 'order': 23}, {'name': 'Yüz Tanıma', 'value': 'Var', 'order': 24}, {'name': 'Slow Motion Video Çekimi', 'value': 'Var', 'order': 25}, {'name': 'Kamera Yapay Zeka (AI) Desteği', 'value': 'Yok', 'order': 26}, {'name': 'Time Lapse Video Çekimi', 'value': 'Var', 'order': 30}, {'name': 'Flaş Türü', 'value': 'Çift LED', 'order': 31}, {'name': 'Phase Detection', 'value': 'Var', 'order': 32}, {'name': 'HDR', 'value': 'Var', 'order': 33}, {'name': 'Zamanlayıcı', 'value': 'Var', 'order': 35}, {'name': 'Otomatik Odaklama', 'value': 'Var', 'order': 36}, {'name': 'Panoroma', 'value': 'Var', 'order': 37}, {'name': 'Coğrafi Konum Ekleme', 'value': 'Var', 'order': 38}], 'order': 3}, {'name': 'Tasarım', 'specEntries': [{'name': 'En', 'value': '75.7 mm', 'order': 1}, {'name': 'Boy', 'value': '150.9 mm', 'order': 2}, {'name': 'Kalınlık', 'value': '8.3 mm', 'order': 3}, {'name': 'Ağırlık', 'value': '194 gr', 'order': 7}, {'name': 'Gövde Malzemesi (Kapak)', 'value': 'Cam', 'order': 15}, {'name': 'Gövde Malzemesi (Çerçeve)', 'value': 'Alüminyum', 'order': 16}, {'name': 'Renk', 'value': 'Siyah', 'order': 31}], 'order': 4}, {'name': 'Batarya Özellikleri', 'specEntries': [{'name': 'Şarj Tipi', 'value': 'Lightning', 'order': 2}, {'name': 'Batarya Tipi', 'value': 'Li-ion', 'order': 11}, {'name': 'Kablosuz Hızlı Şarj', 'value': 'Yok', 'order': 12}, {'name': 'Kablosuz Hızlı Şarj Güç', 'value': 'Yok', 'order': 13}, {'name': 'Çıkarılabilir Batarya', 'value': 'Yok', 'order': 14}, {'name': 'Kablosuz Şarj', 'value': 'Var', 'order': 26}, {'name': 'Hızlı Şarj', 'value': 'Var', 'order': 27}], 'order': 5}, {'name': 'Depolama', 'specEntries': [{'name': 'Dahili Depolama (Hafıza)', 'value': '64 GB', 'order': 5}, {'name': 'Maksimum Hafıza Kartı Kapasitesi', 'value': 'Yok', 'order': 8}, {'name': 'Hafıza Kartı Desteği', 'value': 'Yok', 'order': 31}], 'order': 6}, {'name': 'Bağlantılar', 'specEntries': [{'name': 'Bluetooth Versiyonu', 'value': '5.0', 'order': 3}, {'name': 'Ses Çıkışı', 'value': 'Lightning', 'order': 5}, {'name': '4.5G Desteği', 'value': 'Var', 'order': 11}, {'name': 'Wİ-Fİ', 'value': 'Var', 'order': 11}, {'name': 'Wİ-Fİ Frekansı', 'value': 'Wi-Fi 6', 'order': 12}, {'name': 'Bluetooth', 'value': 'Var', 'order': 13}, {'name': 'Wİ-Fİ Hotspot', 'value': 'Var', 'order': 14}, {'name': 'Navigasyon', 'value': 'Var', 'order': 16}, {'name': '3G İndirme Hızı', 'value': '42.2 Mbps', 'order': 23}, {'name': '3G Yükleme Hızı', 'value': '5.76 Mbps', 'order': 24}, {'name': 'NFC', 'value': 'Var', 'order': 25}, {'name': '5G Desteği', 'value': 'Yok', 'order': 28}, {'name': 'Kızılötesi', 'value': 'Yok', 'order': 29}, {'name': 'USB Type-C', 'value': 'Yok', 'order': 30}], 'order': 7}, {'name': 'Ek Özellikler', 'specEntries': [{'name': 'Kalem', 'value': 'Yok', 'order': 11}, {'name': 'Güvenli Klasör', 'value': 'Yok', 'order': 12}, {'name': 'Antutu Puanı', 'value': '456900', 'order': 13}, {'name': 'Suya Dayanıklılık Seviyesi', 'value': 'IPX8', 'order': 14}, {'name': 'Toza Dayanıklılık Seviyesi', 'value': 'IP6X', 'order': 15}, {'name': 'Parmak İzi Okuyucu', 'value': 'Yok', 'order': 21}, {'name': 'Suya Dayanıklılık', 'value': 'Var', 'order': 23}, {'name': 'Toza Dayanıklılık', 'value': 'Var', 'order': 24}, {'name': 'Çıkış Tarihi', 'value': '2019', 'order': 35}, {'name': 'Parmak İzi Okuyucu Tipi', 'value': 'Yok', 'order': 37}, {'name': 'FM Radyo', 'value': 'Yok', 'order': 38}, {'name': 'Sim Kart Türü', 'value': 'Nano-SIM (4FF)', 'order': 39}], 'order': 8}, {'name': 'Sensörler', 'specEntries': [{'name': 'RGB Işık Sensörü', 'value': 'Yok', 'order': 2}, {'name': 'Bildirim Işığı', 'value': 'Yok', 'order': 8}, {'name': 'Barometre', 'value': 'Var', 'order': 31}, {'name': 'Jiroskop', 'value': 'Var', 'order': 32}, {'name': 'Hall Sensörü', 'value': 'Yok', 'order': 33}, {'name': 'Pusula', 'value': 'Var', 'order': 34}, {'name': 'Yakınlık Sensörü', 'value': 'Var', 'order': 35}, {'name': 'İvme Ölçer', 'value': 'Var', 'order': 36}], 'order': 9}, {'name': 'Kamera Özellikleri(Arka)', 'specEntries': [{'name': 'Elle Odaklama', 'value': 'Var', 'order': 8}, {'name': 'Seri Çekim Modu', 'value': 'Var', 'order': 10}, {'name': 'Zamanlayıcı', 'value': 'Var', 'order': 11}, {'name': 'Portre Modu', 'value': 'Var', 'order': 13}, {'name': 'Geniş Açı', 'value': 'Var', 'order': 13}, {'name': 'Yapay Zeka', 'value': 'Yok', 'order': 14}, {'name': 'Yüz Algılama', 'value': 'Var', 'order': 15}, {'name': 'Görüntü Sabitleyici', 'value': 'Var', 'order': 16}, {'name': 'Manuel Kontrol', 'value': 'Var', 'order': 17}, {'name': 'Hızlı Odaklama', 'value': 'Var', 'order': 52}, {'name': 'Odak Takibi', 'value': 'Var', 'order': 52}, {'name': 'Sesli Komut', 'value': 'Var', 'order': 52}, {'name': 'QR Kod Okuyucu', 'value': 'Yok', 'order': 55}], 'order': 10}, {'name': 'Kamera Özellikleri(Ön)', 'specEntries': [{'name': 'Geniş Açı', 'value': 'Yok', 'order': 2}, {'name': 'Otomatik Odaklama', 'value': 'Var', 'order': 3}, {'name': 'Panorama Özçekim', 'value': 'Yok', 'order': 4}, {'name': 'Seçmeli Odaklama', 'value': 'Yok', 'order': 5}, {'name': 'Sanal Flaş', 'value': 'Var', 'order': 8}, {'name': 'Zamanlayıcı', 'value': 'Var', 'order': 9}, {'name': 'Portre', 'value': 'Var', 'order': 18}, {'name': 'Sesle Komut', 'value': 'Yok', 'order': 19}, {'name': 'Yapay Zeka', 'value': 'Yok', 'order': 20}], 'order': 11}, {'name': 'Kamera Özellikleri(Video)', 'specEntries': [{'name': 'FPS', 'value': '60', 'order': 1}, {'name': 'Çözünürlük Standardı', 'value': '2160p', 'order': 2}, {'name': 'HDR', 'value': 'Var', 'order': 33}, {'name': 'Portre', 'value': 'Yok', 'order': 52}, {'name': 'Görüntü Sabitleme', 'value': 'Var', 'order': 53}, {'name': 'Ağır Çekim', 'value': 'Var', 'order': 54}, {'name': 'Hızlı Çekim', 'value': 'Var', 'order': 55}], 'order': 12}, {'name': 'USB', 'specEntries': [{'name': 'OTG', 'value': 'Var', 'order': 38}, {'name': 'DisplayPort', 'value': 'Yok', 'order': 39}, {'name': 'E-Sim', 'value': 'Var', 'order': 40}, {'name': 'Micro USB', 'value': 'Yok', 'order': 50}, {'name': 'Lightning', 'value': 'Var', 'order': 52}], 'order': 13}], 'topSpecs': [{'name': 'Dahili Depolama (Hafıza)', 'value': '64 GB', 'order': 5}, {'name': 'Diyafram Açıklığı', 'value': 'F1.8', 'order': 9}, {'name': 'Ekran Boyutu', 'value': '6.1 inç', 'order': 3}, {'name': 'Kamera Çözünürlüğü', 'value': '12 MP', 'order': 4}, {'name': 'Ön (Selfie) Kamera Çözünürlüğü', 'value': '12 MP', 'order': 8}], 'unitType': None, 'variantsHeader': 'Renk', 'variants': [{'id': '337337465', 'imageId': 178955343, 'minPrice': 13229, 'shortTitle': 'Beyaz', 'title': 'Apple iPhone 11 64GB 4GB Ram 6.1 inç 12MP Akıllı Cep Telefonu Beyaz', 'url': '/cep-telefonlari/en-ucuz-apple-iphone-11-64gb-4gb-ram-6-1-inc-12mp-akilli-cep-telefonu-beyaz-fiyatlari,337337465', 'unitPrice': None}, {'id': '337339455', 'imageId': 178955504, 'minPrice': 13249, 'shortTitle': 'Sarı', 'title': 'Apple iPhone 11 64GB 4GB Ram 6.1 inç 12MP Akıllı Cep Telefonu Sarı', 'url': '/cep-telefonlari/en-ucuz-apple-iphone-11-64gb-4gb-ram-6-1-inc-12mp-akilli-cep-telefonu-sari-fiyatlari,337339455', 'unitPrice': None}, {'id': '337338130', 'imageId': 178955431, 'minPrice': 13299, 'shortTitle': 'Yeşil', 'title': 'Apple iPhone 11 64GB 4GB Ram 6.1 inç 12MP Akıllı Cep Telefonu Yeşil', 'url': '/cep-telefonlari/en-ucuz-apple-iphone-11-64gb-4gb-ram-6-1-inc-12mp-akilli-cep-telefonu-yesil-fiyatlari,337338130', 'unitPrice': None}, {'id': '337338937', 'imageId': 178955480, 'minPrice': 13299, 'shortTitle': 'Mor', 'title': 'Apple iPhone 11 64GB 4GB Ram 6.1 inç 12MP Akıllı Cep Telefonu Mor', 'url': '/cep-telefonlari/en-ucuz-apple-iphone-11-64gb-4gb-ram-6-1-inc-12mp-akilli-cep-telefonu-mor-fiyatlari,337338937', 'unitPrice': None}, {'id': '337340793', 'imageId': 219571586, 'minPrice': 12986, 'shortTitle': 'Siyah', 'title': 'Apple iPhone 11 64GB 4GB Ram 6.1 inç 12MP Akıllı Cep Telefonu Siyah', 'url': '/cep-telefonlari/en-ucuz-apple-iphone-11-64gb-4gb-ram-6-1-inc-12mp-akilli-cep-telefonu-siyah-fiyatlari,337340793', 'unitPrice': None}, {'id': '337340093', 'imageId': 178955538, 'minPrice': 13385.59, 'shortTitle': 'Kırmızı', 'title': 'Apple iPhone 11 64GB 4GB Ram 6.1 inç 12MP Akıllı Cep Telefonu Kırmızı', 'url': '/cep-telefonlari/en-ucuz-apple-iphone-11-64gb-4gb-ram-6-1-inc-12mp-akilli-cep-telefonu-kirmizi-fiyatlari,337340093', 'unitPrice': None}], 'mainVariantsHeader': 'Kapasite', 'mainVariants': [{'id': '337341638', 'imageId': 178955480, 'minPrice': 12986, 'shortTitle': '64 GB', 'title': 'Apple iPhone 11 64GB 4GB Ram 6.1 inç 12MP Akıllı Cep Telefonu', 'url': '/cep-telefonlari/en-ucuz-apple-iphone-11-64gb-4gb-ram-6-1-inc-12mp-akilli-cep-telefonu-fiyatlari,a337341638'}, {'id': '331840845', 'imageId': 178954771, 'minPrice': 13999, 'shortTitle': '128 GB', 'title': 'Apple iPhone 11 128GB Akıllı Cep Telefonu', 'url': '/cep-telefonlari/en-ucuz-apple-iphone-11-128gb-akilli-cep-telefonu-fiyatlari,a331840845'}, {'id': '337357780', 'imageId': 178954858, 'minPrice': 20899, 'shortTitle': '256 GB', 'title': 'Apple iPhone 11 256GB 4GB Ram 6.1 inç 12MP Akıllı Cep Telefonu', 'url': '/cep-telefonlari/en-ucuz-apple-iphone-11-256gb-4gb-ram-6-1-inc-12mp-akilli-cep-telefonu-fiyatlari,a337357780'}], 'brand': {'id': 4, 'name': 'Apple', 'slug': 'apple'}, 'category': {'id': '130', 'name': 'Cep Telefonları', 'slug': 'cep-telefonlari'}}
```